# Splitting a Website in two sub domains by business activity

Tags: seo, google, domains, subdomain

Hello I am currently working on a website for a company that so far have been manufacturing yarns, however currently they started making towel products and they wanted to somehow differentiate it. So i was wondering if there would be any repercussions if i ware to split the site in two sub-domains like so yarns.site.com and towels.site.com and the main site www.site.com would be like a hub to send the clients on the part that they are interested in be it yarns or towels. And also what if they want to have a shop in the future? Would adding a sub-domain like shop.site.com affect the other two ? And most importantly what would Google say ?

Comment: Be careful not to do too much. If your product lines are not complimentary regarding keywords, then it may make sense to have sub-domains, however, too many sub-domains means a few things: one, more work; two, less search potential for each; three, more confusion for users; four, less value for the parent domain. You want to rank the parent domain. If you have a lot of products, then sub-domains may make sense, but if you have a few products, it will be hard to pull off.

Answer (score 2):

> Hello I am currently working on a website for a company that so far have been manufacturing yarns, however currently they started making towel products and they wanted to somehow differentiate it. So i was wondering if there would be any repercussions if i ware to split the site in two sub-domains ...

there are, see below

> And also what if they want to have a shop in the future? Would adding a sub-domain like shop.site.com affect the other two ?

yes, in the same way, see below

> And most importantly what would Google say ?

I presume you are only referring to Google search and the SEO implications.

Google uses many signals to understand what search keywords each individual page is useful for and the general quality of it's content.

Just one of those signals is using sub-domains to indicate that groups of pages are separate sites entirely (possible owned by different people) or are simply different sections of the same site. Google is of course well aware of both approaches. Google consider using sub-domains as a stronger signal that groups of pages are unrelated.

If you just want to indicate to Google that these are different sections of the same site (and the same quality of content) then it is better to use sub-folders instead of sub-domains (ie www.site.com/towels).

I cannot offer any 100% proof of that as Google are typically very secretive about their search engine and are constantly tweaking it. A reasonably reliable and well-known SEO industry expert discusses the sub-domain topic [here](https://moz.com/blog/subdomains-vs-subfolders-rel-canonical-vs-301-how-to-structure-links-optimally-for-seo-whiteboard-friday).

If you still want to use sub-domains for other reasons such as say print advertising "get your fluffy towels at towels.site.com today!", you can still do that with no SEO impact by using 301 redirects to the main url.

Be aware that SEO is a complex, secretive and ever-changing activity and I would advise you to find an up to date reliable source to gain a basic and broad understanding of it. Acting on snippets of SEO information might lead to difficult-to-fix problems later.